# Handler running after another playbook in ansible role

Tags: ansible

How do handlers behave when they are part of an included playbook ? I am using 3 playbooks and per my understanding ansible runs them in sequence. I have a handler which is configured as part of the second playbook ( checks if the newly created VM is up before proceeding ) however this is running after the third playbook which is yum update.

Main task file in role

---

```
# tasks file for baseline
- include: vmbuild.yml
- include: vmconfig.yml
- include: yum-update.yml
```

handler is configured in handlers/main.yml, shouldnt the third playbook run after the second has completed its tasks ?

Comment: It's not possible to "include a playbook". There is no such thing as `include_playbook`. There is only [`import_playbook`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/import_playbook_module.html#import-playbook-import-a-playbook). You must have seen an error if you included a playbook.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response, i am able to run the playbooks from another yml file which calls for this role. The problem is handlers in the second play are running after the third which is breaking the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this working by defining a `post_tasks` along with the role, this way once all other tasks in playbooks run, last step (yum update) runs fine inheriting the VM's hostname from last steps

Hope this helps someone..